# Why can a unit normal be simplified like this?

Tags: calculus

In my maths textbook, when trying to find a unit normal $n$,

$$n = (2xi + 2yj)/\sqrt{4x^2 +4y^2} = xi + yj$$

How is this possible?

Comment: Surely there is more to it than this. Give us everything the textbook says, or at least identify the book and the page so if someone else has it we can see what's going on.

Comment: Yes thanks, just discovered x^2 + y^2 = 1. Sorry - it's been a long day.

Comment: @Rupert, you can delete your post if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just noting a point. If $$\vec{v}=a\vec{\textbf{i}}+b\vec{\textbf{j}}+c\vec{\textbf{k}}\in\mathbb R^3$$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq 1$ then you can find a unit vector $\vec{n}$ along side $\vec{v}$ as follows: $$\vec{n}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\vec{\textbf{i}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\vec{\textbf{j}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\vec{\textbf{k}}$$

Comment: Thank you, dear Babak. I'll be "around" here and there, to say hello, etc. But won't be able to spend too much time writing answers and such. But I will be sure to say hello, and keep you posted. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: plz don't think of me or any other things.:-) Just try to be here healthier than before, fresh and smiley. Take care of yourself. ;-)

Comment: Oh, but I will miss my good friends here (you, and Amzoti, in particular), so I will certainly want to "touch bases." You are a breath of fresh air, always.